# chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener background Ajax request?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to change the fixed geolocation country of Google search. The only way without using a VPN I have found is adding `gl=[country_code]` to the URL. I created an extension for my use and added that part to the Google search URLs, and it worked. But I recently found that the auto completion (Suggestion) is not changed to the web page's country. That is, even though at the left bottom of Google's home page says "United States", the auto completion is still set to my geo-location, and giving a different list.

After some testing, I have found that Google calls `https://www.google.com/complete/search...` in the background, and if I append `gl=[country_code]` to the URL, I can change the country of auto completion. But adding `https://www.google.com/complete/search?*` like below did not work (`modifyUrl` was not called).

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener
(
    modifyUrl,
    {urls: [
            'https://www.google.com/search?*',
            'https://www.google.com/webhp?*',
            'https://www.google.com/complete/search?*' ],
             types: ['main_frame']},
    ['blocking']
);
```

Is there any way I can modify the auto completion URL? If there is a better way to change the country without using a VPN, I can use that, too.

Answer (score 0):

#### Auto-complete searches in google.com site

These are performed via standard JavaScript XHR/fetch (use devtools to inspect the request's details) so you need to specify the `type` as `xmlhttprequest` when registering a webRequest listener, not `main_frame`.

#### Auto-complete searches in the address bar

These aren't reported to extensions since [Chrome 71](https://crrev.com/c/1242296).

Quoting the reasons behind this decision from [crbug.com/884932](https://crbug.com/884932):

> **browser initiated** requests which may be sensitive in nature or affect browser functionality
>
> - https://update.googleapis.com/service/update2 (component updater)
> - https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/verify (install signer, used for extension install verification)
> - https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/blobs.... (downloading crx packages after sync)
> - https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.... (Extension icon on the install dialog triggered from webstore)
> - https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome-omni.. (related to omnibox)
> - https://www.google.com/async/ddljson?async=ntp:1 (related to ntp doodle)
> - https://www.google.com/chromesuggestions?t=1
> - https://cuscochromeextension-pa.googleapis.com/v1/omniboxsuggestions
> - https://googleapis.com/oauth2... (calls to gaia urls)
>
> For example, one can easily prevent extension install verification or downloading synced extensions by blocking some of these requests. This may have other security implications as well.
>
> We have implemented custom one-off solutions in the past to prevent things like this (e.g. we prevent extensions from intercepting browser initiated requests to some web store urls, safe browsing urls, one google bar requests made on behalf of the NTP etc.).
>
> It seems to me that a more completion solution would be to **prevent extensions from intercepting any non-navigation browser initiated requests.**

The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) was also updated:

> [...] certain requests [...] are hidden [...] https://www.google.com/chrome, **and other sensitive requests core to browser functionality**.

#### Auto-complete searches in the default new/empty tab

The input box in the middle is a "fakebox" that merely focuses the address bar so it's the same as address bar search mentioned in the previous section. The search box be implemented as a real input (see [crbug.com/243926](https://crbug.com/243926)) but it'll be still a part of the core browser UI, hence not exposed to extensions' webRequest.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However, I had already given up the address bar completion, as the requests for that did not even show in the "Network" of the Developer Tools. This question was about the auto completion in the search input field on Google's home page ("https://www.google.com"). Is that also not possible?

Comment: If you mean the actual google.com site then as you can see in devtools, these requests have `type: "xmlhttprequest"`, not `"main_frame"`.